# How can I check if a javascript variable contains a string or not?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable: $form.attr('action') that contains one of the following:

```
action="/Administration/Contents/JsonCreate"
action="/Administration/Contents/JsonEdit"
action="/Administration/Contents/JsonDelete"
```

How can I with an if () statement check to see if it contains the word "JsonEdit" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `indexOf()`:

```
var str = $form.attr('action');

if(str.indexOf("JsonEdit")>=0){
    //do something you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegExp [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to check if you have something there. `test` [returns true if a match is found](http://jsfiddle.net/EKVxe/), and false if not.

```
if(/JsonEdit/.test(action)){
    //there is something
}
```

Comment: I'd say a regex is not appropriate but overkill if you just want to check if a certain static string is inside another string.

Comment: @ThiefMaster—overkill? Hardly, but `indexof` is a lot faster (not that anyone would notice for a one-off).